# Query to Re-index Primary Key of MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I've got a table in MySQL that has a Primary Key Column.

Lets say:

```
ID | Value
1  | One
2  | Two
6  | Three
8  | Four
9  | Five
```

How do I get it to be:

```
ID | Value
1  | One
2  | Two
3  | Three
4  | Four
5  | Five
```

There are no other tables.  Just the one. 
I just want the ID to be in a proper series.

Any suggestion??
A Query perhaps..  :)

Comment: I know about Ordering. That's not what I want.. I want the ID to be in a Perfect Sequence...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is even a simple way to accomplish the result by writing this query

```
SET @newid=0;
UPDATE tablename SET primary_key_id=(@newid:=@newid+1) ORDER BY primary_key_id;
```

This query will reindex the primary key starts from `1`

Comment: This solution is great, but please take into account relation to other tables based on this field that you reiterate ! If you have constraints with update clause on it on the other tables it's ok, if not you should update the ID on the other tables as well ;)

Comment: @qdev If there is any relation between tables then we should not reiterate the primary key.

Comment: working pure solution. Also you need to be careful possible relations on other tables that use the primary key you are updating.

Comment: this solution work fine for primary column but next incremented id column value is different.

Answer (score 11):

Seems to me you have two options.

1) create a new table and copy the existing data over.

2) add another autoincrement field to the existing table, then delete the original column.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD NewIdn INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

Comment: Works Fine.. Thanks for the solution "dbaseman"..  :)

Had to drop the ID column first though as it did 
not allow for two columns with AUTO_INCREMENT.
 "ALTER TABLE `test` DROP COLUMN `id`"

Answer (score 0):

I did this in phpmyadmin by unchecking the A_I box (Auto Increment setting), clicking save, and then checking it again, and clicking save again.