# mysql AUTO_INCREMENT based on another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

How can I auto increment `id` column based on the 0 to max (int) value on the `price` column.

Lets assume that `price is ASC`, I want the `id = 1` increment to start at the $0 mark. What would I have to edit for this code `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` ?

```
id | price | other columns 
1  | 9
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 5
```

into

```
id | price | other columns
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 5
4  | 9
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand your question. Could you please explain it better?

Comment: it seems already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242311/query-to-re-index-primary-key-of-mysql-database

Comment: This is not how __auto__ increment works by definition.

Comment: I want to make auto increment on ID column based on the 0 to max price column

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't do that, that isn't what auto_increment is supposed to do. You can search for stupid answers that tell you how to, but in a few days you'll be asking a whole different array of questions that will spawn from misuse of auto_increment. It's job is not to hand out pretty sequential numbers. If you understand that, then you can utilize triggers and create another column to do nice numbering based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

sorry,
 you must send 2 Querys. The first to set rhe Variable nr to 0 and
then the update statement

```
SET @nr:=0;
UPDATE your_table_name t
  SET t.id = @nr:=@nr+1
  ORDER BY t.price ASC;
```

Comment: You do realize you can edit an answer you posted and update it? What's the point of 4 wrong answers here?

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong but it does not seem to work. It takes a really long time and does not finish.

Answer (score 0):

A easy Way ist to create a new table with one column more with autoincrement.

```
intert into newtable select '',o.* from oldtable o order by o.price asc;
```

Then they insert all row in the right order from price in the new table.

Comment: I don't want to make a new table every time just for this

Comment: then the row number every time changed when you sort the result by price with new rows.

Comment: has to be a way to just update the current `id` column based on the `price` column

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to have a row with rownumber, so you can do it like this:

```
SELECT @nr:=@nr+1 AS id,c.* FROM mytable c, (SELECT @nr:=0) tmp;
```

Comment: if I create a new column `f_id` how would I be able to auto increment the new column based on the `price` asc column? And if this is possible would I be able to delete old `f_id` column and create a new `f_id` column with auto increment whenever I update the db?

Answer (score 0):

the feld x is NOT autoincrement. its only a non uniqe index

```
SET @nr:=0;
UPDATE newtable n SET n.x = @nr:=@nr+1 ORDER BY n.price ASC;
```

Comment: sorry I'm a little new. not sure how I would use this approach