# Renumber keys in compound unique constraint

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
| id | sub_id | fk_id |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 1      | 1     |
| 2  | 2      | 1     |
| 3  | 3      | 1     |
| 4  | 4      | 1     |
| 5  | 5      | 1     |
| 6  | 1      | 2     |
| 7  | 2      | 2     |
| 8  | 3      | 2     |
| 9  | 4      | 2     |
| 10 | 5      | 2     |
```

Within this table `id` is the primary key, and `sub_id` and `fk_id` make up a compound unique key, where `fk_id` is the primary key in another table.

I've found myself in the situation where I need to be able to remove rows within the table, but then renumber sub_id so that there aren't any gaps, e.g. remove `(1, 1, 1)` and all rows where `fk_id=1` have their respective `sub_id` renumbered as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I also need to be able to remove one or more rows at a time, then trigger the re-numbering (as I assume it's inefficient to try and renumber them multiple times when once will suffice). However, there's a maximum of 60 rows for each value of `fk_id` but there can be thousands of different values of `fk_id`.

How should I go about the re-numbering? I'm think some sort of INSERT ... SELECT query, but I can't get my head around how it should work.

Comment: You are doing something strange, how about normalizing your tables? It could help you down the road, read about 1NF

Comment: Could you clarify how you think this is strange? I don't see how it doesn't follow the criteria of [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

You can renumber the rows for a given `fk_id` using this query:

```sql
select t_renum.*, count(t_lower.id) as new_sub_id
from mytable t_renum
join mytable t_lower
    on  t_lower.fk_id = t_renum.fk_id
    and t_lower.id <= t_renum.id
where t_renum.fk_id = @renumber_fk_id
group by t_renum.id
```

The result can be joined with the original table for update like this:

```sql
update mytable t
join (
    select t_renum.*, count(t_lower.id) as new_sub_id
    from mytable t_renum
    join mytable t_lower
        on  t_lower.fk_id = t_renum.fk_id
        and t_lower.id <= t_renum.id
    where t_renum.fk_id = @renumber_fk_id
    group by t_renum.id 
) t_renum using (id)
set t.sub_id = t_renum.new_sub_id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69df88/1)

Answer (score 0):

After digging around more, I discovered another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30425231/1942596) that was remarkably simple and avoided the need for a new table which is recommended in many similar questions. I converted it to a stored procedure which suits my needs better:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reindex (IN fk_key INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    SET @num := 0;

    UPDATE example
        SET sub_id = (@num := @num + 1)
        WHERE fk_id = fk_key
        ORDER BY id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```